# Convert join to ObservableCollection in property setter returns empty list

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, observablecollection

I encountered a strange behaviour with `LINQ` and `ObservableCollection`.

I have a `LINQ` query that fetches my `Users` with their assigned `Roles`. This queries a `left outer join`, which is correct.

```
context.Users.Select(x => new UserModel()
             {
                 UserID = x.UserID,
                 Username = x.Username,
                 AssignedRoles = x.UserRoles.Select(y => new RoleModel()
                 {
                     RoleID = y.RoleID,
                 }).ToList()
             }));
```

The query that is generated with this `LINQ statement` is correct.

The strange behaviour occurs when I edit the setter of my `AssignedRoles` property in my `User` model.
When I assign the correctly fetched `AssignedRoles` directly to my property, the correct result is shown in my UI.

```
public ICollection<RoleModel> AssignedRoles
{
    get
    {
        return this.assignedRoles;
    }
    set
    {
        this.assignedRoles = value;
    }
}
```

But when I convert the fetched values to an `ObservableCollection`, the list stays empty.

```
public ICollection<RoleModel> AssignedRoles
{
    get
    {
        return this.assignedRoles;
    }
    set
    {
        this.assignedRoles = new ObservableCollection<RoleModel>(value);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why this happens?

I know I can convert my `AssignedRoles` to an `ObservableCollection` and keeping the correct result like this:

```
public ICollection<RoleModel> AssignedRoles
{
    get
    {
        if (!(this.assignedRoles is ObservableCollection<RoleModel>))
            this.assignedRoles = new ObservableCollection<RoleModel>(this.assignedRoles);

        return this.assignedRoles;
    }
    set
    {
        this.assignedRoles = value;
    }
}
```

But this looks a bit strange.

**EDIT**

I guess it has something to do with LINQ and it's deferred execution?
I've solved it by retrieving the results as an `anonymous object`. Then I iterate over the result and create my `UserModel`.

Thanks!
Loetn

Comment: are you saying that your third example works, but your second example doesn't ? that is indeed strange. Consider posting the code where you assign the AssignedRole property

Comment: @Tewr I assign the `AssignedRole` property in my linq query. I guess it has something to do with deferred execution of the linq query?

Comment: ah ok I didn't see that, sorry. Yes deferred execution is often a gotcha with Linq. Have you tried putting a ToList() on the outter expression to execute it immediately? `context.Users.Select(...).ToList()`

Comment: @Tewr Already tried that. To be honest, in my original code, the query is included into a `new ObservableCollection(query)`. For now, I fetch the result and loop through it and add them to a new `ObservableCollection`. But I still want to know why this behaviour happens... :)

Comment: Well, it's difficult to tell. when you say "list stays empty", what does that mean? in the wpf interface? in the debugger? In my experience with wpf and bindings, ObservableCollections should be instanciated as seldom as possible, preferably in the constructor, and then use add and remove. Otherwise the binding system in wpf might loose track of your instance. In your case you probably need AddRange, so consider [ObservableRangeCollection](http://manageo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/UIElements/ObservableRangeCollection.cs).

Comment: It's count is 0. It is empty in the debugger, thus also in the UI. I'm certain that the Binding isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when `AssignedRoles` is updated you do not raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event. Any databinding involving this property will not update because there is no notification about the change of the property value.

If you do not reassign the `ObservableCollection` but only use a single instance then the UI will update based on changes done to this instance explaining the behavior you experience.

Comment: Already tried the `PropertyChanged` event and it doesn't help. When I execute the query, it doesn't even add items to my `AssignedRoles` list.